# don't present camera in full screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way presenting the camera interface not in full screen specially in the iPad?

I've tried the cameraOverlay but it still present the camera UI in full screen.

Answer (score 0):

just add an additional view object to your nib/storyboard and use that as your camera interface.